# How to use custom keys in laravel routes without scoping?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

When using custom keys Laravel forces us with scoping, for example, I have a route to getting a country and a post

```
api/countries/{country:slug}/posts/{post:slug}
```

but I can't get that using slug key because it doesn't have a relation with country, and in this case, I want to handle scope myself and I don't need implicitly scope binding, but I get an error (Call to undefined method App\Country::posts() ).
so because of that I cant using this Laravel feature. is there a way to turn the implicitly scope binding off?

Comment: Please explain more with what you've tried so far in code, and the meaning of this `Call to undefined method App\Country::posts() ` is that you haven't made post relationship with the country model class

Comment: @Vipertecpro I think all the information is there. When using custom keys, nested route parameters are "scoped" by higher level ones. So it's trying to find a post as a child of the country; and the OP has said that the models are not nested like that so it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

If the posts are not related to the countries, it may not make sense to nest them in the URI?

But, nonetheless, to answer your question, you need to do one of two things:

1. Instead of setting {country:slug}, just use {country} and then override `getKeyRouteName()` function on your Country and Post models.
2. Alternatively, especially if you want to use the ID elsewhere, use [explicit model binding.](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#explicit-binding)

**To use a slug without custom keys in the routes file**

```
class Post
{
    [...]

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

**To use explicit route model binding**

Add the following to the boot() method of your RouteServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('post', function ($value) {
        return App\Post::where('slug', $value)->firstOrFail();
    });
}
```